# CLLocationManagerDelegate's (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error not called when in App is in BG

Tags: ios, delegates, location, didfailwitherror

My locationManager is setup to work in BG (allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates + in capability Background Modes: location updates is checked).

My CLLocationManagerDelegate's

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
```

works fine when application is in BG.

But,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Does not get called when in the application is in BG.
When the application is returned to FG then the method is called.

- I checked this on iOS 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: To get the delegate didFailWithError to be called I switch location services off.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Location updates are delivered in the background.  Failure isn't a location update, it is location service status update.